# Probem while reading field in document from firestore in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

```
 private fun logInRegisteredUser() {

        if (validateLoginDetails()) {

            // Show the progress dialog.
            showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))

            // Get the text from editText and trim the space
            val email = et_email.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
            val password = et_password.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }

            // Log-In using FirebaseAuth
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->

                    // Hide the progress dialog
                    hideProgressDialog()

                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                       val currrentUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
                       /* if (currrentUser != null) {
                            val washingtonre = mFireStore.collection("use").document(currrentUser.uid)

                            washingtonre.get().addOnSuccessListener(object: OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot> {
                                override fun onSuccess(documentSnapshot:DocumentSnapshot) {
                                    if (documentSnapshot.exists())
                                    {
                                        var arrList = ArrayList<String>()
                                        arrList = documentSnapshot.get("organization") as ArrayList<String>
                                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"$arrList",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                                        for (i in 0 until arrList.size)
                                        {
                                            //Traversing the list
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }*/

                        if (currrentUser != null) {

                            val c = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                            val d = c.collection("users").document(currrentUser.uid)
                            d.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                                if (document != null) {


                                    arrList = document.get("organization") as ArrayList<String>
                                    if (arrList.size>1) {


                                        val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, companyDetails::class.java)
                                        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", arrList)
                                        startActivity(intent)




                                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "$arrList", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                                    }
                                    else if (arrList.size<=1) {
                                        val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                                        startActivity(intent)
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("Tag", "No such document")
                                }
                            }
                                    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                                        Log.d("TAG", "get failed with ", exception)
                                    }


                        }



                    } else {
                        showErrorSnackBar(task.exception!!.message.toString(), true)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

This is my code to validate login details. When login button is pressed this code is executed.
Now I want to check an array field named 'organization' in firestore to check wheather the user has two or more companies to his credits. Now when I run the app if organization field doesnt exist my app crashes. I want the app to work even if the organization field doesnt exist. How to change the codes for that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vovay.jpg)

Comment: If the app crashes, there'll be an error message and stack trace in its logcat output. Please find those and add them to your question (there's an edit link right under it).

Comment: Please add it to your question, what Frank van Puffelen asked for, and please also respond with @.